# Display the size and format of a file attached to an article

Tags: 8, files

I'm trying to display the format and size of a file attached to an article. Its system name is *field_file*.

So far, I've succeeded to load an article in my *my_theme*.theme file and the *field_file* field attached to it:

`$article = Node::load($article_nid);
$variables['file'] = $article->get('field_file');`

then use its uri in a twig file: 
`{{file_url(file.entity.fileuri)}}`

Now I'm trying to display its format and size. I tried `{{file.entity.format}}` and `{{file.entity.filesize}}` without success.

Does anyone have a clue how to do it? I'm still new to Drupal plugins and entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [getSize](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Entity%21File.php/function/File%3A%3AgetSize/8.2.x) and [getMimeType](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21FileInterface.php/function/FileInterface%3A%3AgetMimeType/8.2.x) in your *my_theme.theme* as in the example below

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  $type = $node->getType();
  if( $type == "article" && $node->hasField('field_file')){
      //next gets FieldItemList
      //$file = $node->get('field_file');  

      //you need get the file entity
      $file = $node->get('field_file')->entity;
      $vars["size"] = $file->getSize();
      $vars["type"] = $file->getMimeType();     
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried the first method, but since my field is   a _FieldItemList_ field and not a type _File_ field (no idea why), it doesn't work

Comment: `$node->get('field_file')->entity` will give you the entity, look at example above

Comment: Do you then display the file type of field 'field_file'  using this in the twig file: 
`{{type}}`